# How can i make BeautifulSoup finde more than one tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I iam testing a programm for printing the content of wikipedia into the prompt. I alrready got some output but its a bit messy. So i thought to only get the content of tags `<p>` and `<b>` that are the two which wikipedia uses to show the content. Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = input("Enter the url (only wikipedia supported, default url https://?.wikipedia.org/wiki) :  ")



page = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
html_doc = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')





for x in soup.find_all('p').find_all('b'):
    print(x.string)
```

The interrogation mark is because wikipedia shows the lenguage there so it depends. As you see i added one more .find_all with  because i didn´t know how to add it. Sorry for my bad english and my bad code because i am not very related to this request field. Thanks

Comment: So do you want search for all `<b>` tags that are under `<p>` tags? Or for all `<b>` tags AND `<p>` tags?

Comment: for b and p tags

Comment: You should have gotten an error because `find_all` is not a method for a `ResultSet`. Can you post the traceback so people see what hte problem is?

Answer (score 0):

`BeautifulSoup.find_all` returns a `ResultSet` which is essentially a list of elements. You need to iterate through that list for the second operation yourself.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = input("Enter the url (only wikipedia supported, default url https://?.wikipedia.org/wiki) :  ")

page = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
html_doc = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for elem in soup.find_all('p'):
    for x in elem.find_all('b'):
        print(x.string)
```

Comment: With that code I get only the words that are inside the <b> tag which is in turn inside the <p> tag. What I need are the words inside the <p> tag as well as the <b> tag inside the <p> tag. Always thanks for helping me

Comment: What do you mean by "as well"? Do you want to ignore contents of tags other than `<b>`, if they happen to occur within `<p>`?